# How to avoid saving subfolders when saving a file?

Tags: python, django, rar

The function creates a folder and saves a file into it. Then the folder is packed into a rar archive and sent to the user, and the newly created folder and archive are deleted from the server after.

**code.py**

```
new_file_name = self.generate_file_name(rfi, vendor, current_scoring_round)

path_to_temp_folder = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)
if not os.path.exists(f'{path_to_temp_folder}/temp_folder'):
    pathlib.Path(f'{path_to_temp_folder}/temp_folder').mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

wb.save(f'{path_to_temp_folder}/temp_folder/{new_file_name}') #save xlsx file from openpyxl library

archive = self.generate_zip_name(rfi) # generate name for archive

to_rar = f'{path_to_temp_folder}/temp_folder'
patoolib.create_archive(archive, (to_rar,))  # patoolib - to .rar converter 

to_download = f'{path_to_temp_folder}/{archive}'

if os.path.exists(to_download):
try:
    with open(to_download, 'rb') as fh:
        response = HttpResponse(fh.read(),
                                content_type="content_type='application/vnd.rar'")
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename= "{}"'.format(archive)
        return response
finally:
    shutil.rmtree(to_rar, ignore_errors=True)
    default_storage.delete(to_download)
```

Everything work, but the problem is that the downloaded archive contains subfolders - paths to the saved file.

**Expected result:**

```
folder.rar
    file.xlsx
```

**Actual result:**

```
folder.rar
    /home
        /y700
            /projects
                file.xlsx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation to patool is minimal. It certainly seems to suggest that this should be possible by passing the path to the file in the `create-archive` command. I've tried this though, and it appears not.

So the only option, probably, is to change the working directory to the location of the `test.xlsx` file:

```
import patoolib
import os

new_file_name = self.generate_file_name(rfi, vendor, current_scoring_round)

path_to_temp_folder = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)
if not os.path.exists(f'{path_to_temp_folder}/temp_folder'):
    pathlib.Path(f'{path_to_temp_folder}/temp_folder').mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

wb.save(f'{path_to_temp_folder}/temp_folder/{new_file_name}') #save xlsx file from openpyxl library

archive = self.generate_zip_name(rfi) # generate name for archive

to_rar = f'{path_to_temp_folder}/temp_folder'

cwd=os.getcwd()
os.chdir('to_rar')
patoolib.create_archive(cwd+archive, ({new_file_name},))  # patoolib - to .rar converter     
os.chdir('cwd')

to_download = f'{path_to_temp_folder}/{archive}'

if os.path.exists(to_download):
try:
    with open(to_download, 'rb') as fh:
        response = HttpResponse(fh.read(),
                                content_type="content_type='application/vnd.rar'")
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename= "{}"'.format(archive)
        return response
finally:
    shutil.rmtree(to_rar, ignore_errors=True)
    default_storage.delete(to_download)
```

This works on my system, for example, and I get a single file in the archive (using tar, because I don't have rar installed):

```
import patoolib
import os

cwd=os.getcwd()
os.chdir('foo/bar/baz/qux/')
patoolib.create_archive(cwd+'/foo.tar.gz',('test.txt',))
os.chdir(cwd)
```

Note that you should really use `os.path.join` rather than concatenating strings, but this was just a quick & dirty test.

Comment: I got `patoolib.util.PatoolError: file tets.xlsx was not found`  Where tets.xlsx - is `{new_file_name}`
`